# Should I use mixins or an utility class?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, es6-class

I have a Vue.js project that use one method in multiple files, so I create an utility class to write this method there, something like:

```
export class Util{
  doSomething(){
    return 'something'
  }
}
```

But I know that I can do it using mixins, like:

```
export const myMixin = {
   methods: {
     doSomething(){
       return 'something'
     }
   }
}
```

Should I use mixin or an utility class?

When should I use one of them?

Comment: Depends on how doSomething is used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a great question. Unfortunately, there is no precise answer but I'll provide some guidelines based on my own experience working with a large Vue codebase.

**Mixins**

Mixins are ideal for situations where you have a collection of interdependent non-side-effect-free code that you'd like to share between components.

In my case, I have an `input` mixin that defines `props`, some `data` (unique ids for input and error elements), and methods for emitting events like `blur`. It's ~60 lines of code, that I'd otherwise have to retype for each of nine different components.

The benefits of a mixin are similar to that of an inherited class in traditional OOP. I.e. code reuse and complexity encapsulation.

The primary disadvantage of a mixin, is that it can make your code harder to read. Imagine you come back to work on the `AppTextArea` component six months later, and it isn't obvious how and why certain things work or where they are defined... then you remember it uses a mixin, and then you have to dive into the mixin code... In other words it makes for implicit, rather than explicit implementations.

**Shared Functions**

Shared functions are ideal for situations where you can reuse units of side-effect-free code in your application.

In my case, I have a `date` library with a `formatBySlash` function which takes a `Date` object and returns something like `"5/12/2018"`. I've added it as a global filter, so I can do things like `{{ post.createdAt | formatBySlash }}` in my templates. Additionally I can import the function and use it directly in a method or computed property.

Shared functions are flexible, easy to test, and make your code more explicit.

---

In summary, I'd generally recommend writing a shared function unless your use case really requires that it be a mixin.

Comment: I'm curious how do you manage the business logic in Vue. I saw some mixin classes doing network calls, and I found it smelly. I rather created minimum dependency simple es6 Class-es and encapsulate the business logic there (similar how Angular has services).

Have you ever managed business logic in Mixins? How do you manage business logic in your Vue apps?

Comment: I recommend moving more complex, non-UI code into file(s) separate from your components. In my case I have a `/lib` directory where I store these functions/classes. If you have a specific use case you'd like help with, I'd recommend opening a new question.

Answer (score 5):

If `doSomething` has a dependency on the component (it uses certain data property, or it relies on `this.$el`, etc...), you should think on writing it as a mixin.

Otherwise, if it can be used in another context besides a Vue component, use an utility class or function. If it's just one method you don't need to create a class. You can also export functions.